# I use "\mathrm" for preventing Latex to make subscript text italic, but it changes the font to default as well

Tags: fonts, subscripts, italic, mathrm

For a part of document in LNCS format (Lecture Note for Computer Science) I changed the default font to `concmath` font.

I also need to prevent `subscript` text of this part to be `italic`, and for this, I use `\mathrm`, where it works in general.

The problem however is that `\mathrm` changes the font type to default font as well; what I do not want to happen.

**Is there any alternative?**

Example of the code:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
        
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \newenvironment{concmath}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}{\ignorespaces}
        \begin{document}   
                \begin{small}
                    \begin{concmath}
                
                $ \mathrm{T_{i}} $: $ \mathrm{U_{x}} $ + $ \mathrm{U_{y}} $\\
            
                    \end{concmath}
                \end{small}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) showing the problem?

Comment: @Vincent , I added an example of the code.

Comment: Can you make it compilable? It should start with ``\documentclass{...}`` and end with ``\end{document}``.

Comment: @Vincent , I added some necessary elements such as LNCS class etc. I am not however sure if it is now compilable.

Comment: It is almost! You should remove the last ``\\``, or you will get an error when compiling it. So you want the subscripts to be upright, but the other symbols in italic as usual? For example, you want the ``T`` to be in italic and the ``i`` to be upright?

Comment: @Vincent , The last \\ is now removed. No, It's not the case in fact ... All the text should NOT be italic, also All the text should be written by font `concmath`. The problem is that although preventing `italic` works well by using `mathrm` ; BUT the font of the text inside `mathrm` is changed to the default (i.e. it is NOT in `concmath`). How to keep font of inside `mathrm`  (for example, `T_{i}`) as `concmath` ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to define a math version.

Since the code doesn't depend on the class, I used `article`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareMathVersion{concmath}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{concmath}{\encodingdefault}{ccr}{m}{n}

\newenvironment{concmath}
  {\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont\mathversion{concmath}}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}   

This is normal text

\begin{concmath}
This is ccr $ \mathrm{T_{i}} $: $ \mathrm{U_{x}} $ + $ \mathrm{U_{y}} $
\end{concmath}

This is again normal

\end{document}
```

I also made some changes. First, avoid `\\` to end lines. Second, avoid `\begin{small}...\end{small}`, because it will most likely produce uneven line spacing. It's not clear how you will be using this and why `\small`, so I removed it.

[image]